# Where did my dog in Minecraft go?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I had a pet dog in Minecraft Education Edition and I died fighting a skeleton. I spawn in my bed and I go back to the place where I died at. I can't find my dog anywhere, and he wasn't at my house. Where did my beloved dog go?

Comment: Hi Flara Flames, and welcome to arqade! We cannot help you with this answer sinse we cannot troubleshoot this. We cannot "know" where your dog went. Meaby it is dead. We dont know, nor can we help

Comment: @GamerM no, we can't tell OP *where* to find the dog, but we can help them by telling them *how*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animals in Minecraft have particular behaviours, that might help you track down your dog. In this case, dogs will attack skeletons of their own accord, so it's entirely possible that after you died, it chased after the skeleton that attacked you, and continued after another one nearby.

You can also use a command to teleport wolves to your location, which should include your currently tamed wolf:

```
/tp @e[type=Wolf] @p
```

This command will tp *all* nearby wolves to you, so with some work, you might be able to alter the command to tp *only* your wolf to you

```
/tp @e[type=Wolf{Owner:<playername>}] @p
```

<sup>Don't know if that will work - syntax might need some work.</sup>

Unfortunately however, wolves are not invincible, so there is the potential that it might have died, fighting the skeleton that killed you, or another one nearby. In this situation, a notification should have appeared in chat.

Comment: The correct syntax for the second command would be `/tp @e[type=Wolf,nbt={Owner:<playername>}] @p` (at least that is the syntax for checking for NBT; the NBT for a tamed wolf is probably wrong too)